# How to index JSONB column with dynamic keys

Tags: postgresql, index

I have a table `tickets` which can contain custom fields. It's implemented using a jsonb column `tickets`.`custom_fields`, which contains data in the format `{ "<field_id>":<field_value> }`. The <field_id> comes from a `fields` table.

e.g. with the following `fields` table

| id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Text |
| 2 | Score | Number |

consider a ticket with custom_fields as `{ "1": "Field Value #1", "2": 100 }`

As new fields can be added and deleted from fields table, the keys for `custom_fields` jsonb column will keep changing. These custom fields can be filtered on in the UI and as such will  require querying capabilities.

e.g.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "tickets"
WHERE
    CAST("tickets".custom_fields ->> '2' AS DOUBLE PRECISION) > 75
```

I have tried GIN index on `custom_fields`:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_gin_tickets_custom_fields ON tickets USING gin(custom_fields);
```

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=22092.83..22092.84 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=34.548..36.019 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=22092.62..22092.83 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=34.538..36.013 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=21092.62..21092.63 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=32.509..32.510 rows=1 loops=3)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tickets  (cost=0.00..20948.08 rows=57818 width=0) (actual time=9.096..32.504 rows=3 loops=3)
                    Filter: (((custom_fields ->> '2'::text))::double precision > '75'::double precision)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 138760
Planning Time: 0.077 ms
Execution Time: 36.043 ms
```

Questions:

1. How can I index the column that would result in index scan for the filtering queries.
2. Is there a better way to design the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explain analyze you're using the `->>` operator based on this line in your output:

```
Filter: (((custom_fields ->> '2'::text))::double precision > '75'::double precision)
```

Currently the `->>` operator is not supported for indexing. GIN indexes currently only support the following operators (depending on what operator class you defined the index with):

`?, ?|, ?&, @>, @?, @@`

You may find the full documentation as to what is supported [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) which explains the different operator classes (such as `jsonb_path_ops` which does not support key-exists operators).

So your current query will not be able to use the index, however you may use the @> operator to achieve a similar result but be able to use that index:

```
select *
from foo f
where f.jsonb @> '{"key_to_search":"value_to_match"}'
```

As for the "is there any better design" question. Unfortunately, cannot comment on it as I would need to know more details about the business requirement and the design of your system.

Answer (score 1):

GIN indexes do not support inequality operators, so you can't do what you want very effectively with a GIN index.  They do support partial matches, so perhaps you could support inequality (in only one direction) by mapping that to a partial match, if you were willing to write your own implementations to do that.

You could use functional indexes, but then you would need to add a new index every time a new key (which you want to search on for inequality) was introduced. This is probably what I would do.

Assuming you are unwilling to do that, a better design would be to normalize the data into (at least) 2 tables, using an EAV design.  Note that EAV is itself usually considered a poor design--but not all poor designs are equally poor.  A query like `WHERE field_num=2 and field_value >75` would use a multicolumn index on `(field_num, field_value)`.